# Виджеты ВК и пользователи из Украины

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, вконтакте

Столкнулся с такой трудностью: если установлен виджет, например, группы вк, и у пользователя из Украины нет VPN, то страница грузится бесконечно или же частично прогружается. Вся проблема в этом скрипте `<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?154"></script>`. Если разместить его в начале документа, так вообще не загрузится сайт. Такое впечатление, что интерпретатор бесконечно ожидает ответа скрипта. Как можно пофиксить эту проблему?  Например, может, асинхронно отправить запрос и если нет ответа некоторое время, обрывать соединение?

Comment: Временно добавил отслеживание по ip если из UA то просто не выполнять скрипт, но это плохое решение ведь много людей пользуеются vpn.

Comment: так это решение вам подойдет, так как люди с Украины которые используют VPN не будут иметь Украинский IP

Comment: Запустите скрипт в футере как async defer

Comment: Я не спец в сетевых технологиях, но vpn не скрывает основной ip

Comment: "Запустите скрипт в футере как async defer – KAGG Design" Уважаемый KAGG Design сделал как Вы сказали но столкнулся с трудностью когда анимация загрузки крутится безумно долго секунд 30, некоторых пользователей это сводит сума ) Как избавиться от этого? Можно как-то ограничить конкретно этот скрипт временем выполнения, а точней ожидания ответа. Например если ждем больше секунды ответа нет то вырубаем скрипт

Comment: Вы когда пишете кому-то, ставьте @ перед именем. Я случайно увидел ваш комментарий. Автор вопроса получает уведомления о всех комментариях, автор ответа - о всех комментариях под ответом. Остальных надо уведомлять с помощью @.

Comment: У вас тут ещё и прелоадер. Напишу ответ тогда.

Answer (score 0):

Прелоадер завершает работу по событию load. Чтобы ваш скрипт vk не мешал показать страницу, его надо запускать после события load.

Для этого уберите его запуск из php кода и добавьте запуск в футере такого скрипта:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    $.getScript("//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?154");
});
```